# Is the use of "Disclaimer" to disclose existent affiliation correct?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

We all know that on Stack Exchange users are required to disclose affiliation with links and potential promotions they post. In case of being unaffiliated, one often writes a "disclaimer". [Searching for the word "disclaimer" on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=disclaimer&mixed=0) yields some less comprehensible results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/5958455):

> disclaimer: I'm the author

There are plenty of other results where something like "I wrote this" follows an opening of "Disclaimer". Is this an appropriate or correct usage?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

It's short, to the point, and leaves no room for ambiguity; in that answer, it must apply to the preceding link.

Except that this is a community wiki answer, which makes it less clear *who* the post author is (after all, somebody rewriting the answer could end up being the 'main' author according to the system). Therefore, [I tweaked it a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2117523/revisions); it now reads:

> (disclaimer: I, @broofa, am the author)

Comment: I didn't find a tag [word-usage] on MSE, but what I intended was "another word would be more suitable than *disclaimer*". Disclaimer to some extent means "I'm not responsible for this" and thus makes less sense when applied to links of one's own.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I think the usage of the word has evolved a bit, but I'm pretty sure I have seen this regularly outside Stack Exchange as well.

Answer (score 7):

I personally don't see any issues with it. However, if you're uncomfortable with the *possible* duplicate meaning, you could always use [Full Disclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_disclosure).

> Full disclosure, the acknowledgement of possible conflicts of interest
>   in one's work

For example,

> Full Disclosure: I'm the author